# Multiple URLs in manifest.json file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am trying to build a Chrome plugin. In the main folder, I have a popup.html which runs by default and uses the following syntax in manifest.json

```
"browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
```

the popup.html is working absolutely fine

what is my popup.html is doing?

It is inputting email from the user and storing it in local phpmyadmin.
Following is the code of **popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html style="min-width:350px;">
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>   
  </head>
  <body>
<h3> Enter email </h3>

<form action=”info.php” method=”post”>
Enter email: <input type=”email” name=”email” />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

The form action is linked to info.php where the php connects the database and inserts the data into the table in phpMyAdmin.
Following is the **info.php code**

```
<html>

<body>

<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
if (!$con)
{
    echo'Could not connect to the server';
}
if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'test'))
{
    echo 'Database Not Selected';
}
$Email = $_POST[email];

$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table(Email) VALUES ('$Email')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo 'Could not add to database';
}

else
{
    echo 'Thank you the data is added';
}

header("refresh:2; url=popup.html");
?>
</body>

</html>
```

What problem am I facing?
After I enter the email in the input field it gives an error that **Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

Maybe I am getting this error because info.php has to added in the manifest file? If this is the problem then how can I add multiple urls in the manifest.json file?

Comment: The browsers don't have a built-in PHP engine so linking to a `.php` file without a full URL simply open the file as a local html page inside the extension directory. You probably want to use `action="http://localhost/info.php"`.

Comment: @wOxxOm info.html is in the same folder as that of popup.html still i would need to do this?

Comment: The browsers don't have a built-in PHP engine so it doesn't matter how you name the file or where you put it inside your extension directory. If you want PHP being processed you need a separate server.

Comment: @wOxxOm so what if i host info.php online on free web hosting websites? would it work? what do you suggest

Comment: Well, go ahead.

Comment: On the other hand, this is not how extensions are usually implemented. A proper solution is to use an API via `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()`.

Comment: @wOxxOm i am a beginner to this. Could you please elaborate

Comment: That's a broad topic. Find examples and modify them to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your header won't work, since you have already echoed output.

Instead of outputting immediately, stick the output into an $html variable.

This might not completely fix your issue? But it will fix the header.

```
<?php 

$html = '';

$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
if (!$con)
{
    $html .= 'Could not connect to the server';
}
if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'test'))
{
    $html .= 'Database Not Selected';
}
$Email = $_POST[email];

$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table(Email) VALUES ('$Email')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    $html .= 'Could not add to database';
}

if (empty($html)) {
    header("refresh:2; url=popup.html");
} 

echo $html;
```

Comment: i thought you might, since no mention of that error appears anywhere in your code. However your header issue is now fixed! Search your code for the error message

Comment: Also, delete the else section 'the data was added'. We dont want output on success, just the header call. Updating my answer

Comment: The browsers don't have a built-in PHP engine so the contents of the file is interpreted as a normal HTML, all PHP instructions are ignored.

Comment: you need to attach your PHP to your web server, if not already, and not open the files directly

Answer (score 0):

with @wOxxOm help the problem was solved.
In the **popup.html** instead of giving info.html directly, it would have been through the server such as `http://localhost/foldername/info.php`